# Cyclic type definition in Coq

Tags: coq

I am trying to implement the following:

[image: t ::= x | ( ) | case t of () | (t 1 , t 2) | pi_i t | in_i t | ... | suspend e]

[image: e ::= x | ( ) | (e 1 , e 2 ) | ... | t]

Using inductives, *t* depends on *e* and vice versa. How can I implement it in Coq? I cannot use `e` when I haven't yet defined it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coq allows mutually inductive types:

```
Inductive t :=
  | Suspend : e -> t
  | ...
with e :=
  | T : t -> e
  | ...
```

See the reference manual for more details: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/cic.html#inductive-definitions